# EXCEPTION while creating a highlight directive

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to create a simple directive in Angular 2 which highlights the content inside an html element.

Here is my code:

**main.ts**

```
import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {HighLightCmp} from "./highlight.component";

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `

    <div highlight>
        Highlight me.
    </div>
        `,
    directives: [HighLightCmp]
})
class AppCmp{

    constructor(){}
}

bootstrap(AppCmp);
```

**highlight.component.ts**

```
import {ElementRef,Renderer,Directive,OnInit} from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
    selector: "[highlight]"
})
export class HighLightCmp implements OnInit{

    private color: "green";

    constructor(private _elRef:ElementRef,private _renderer:Renderer){}

    ngOnInit(){
        this._renderer.setElementStyle(this._elRef,"background-color",this.color);
    }
}
```

But I am getting the following exception while running

> EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot set property 'background-color' of
>   undefined

I re-produced the problem [here on plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/518t2oYcX86llWwrV8nO?p=preview)

You can see the error message in the console. Any thoughts?

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Don't know if you saw my answer already. I added a few things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**some issues**

This changed a while ago, maybe you find this in an outdated example. Since a while the `Renderer` methods need the `nativeElement` being passed instead of `ElementRef`:

```
this._renderer.setElementStyle(this._elRef.nativeElement, "background-color",this.color);
```

There is also an error in the variable definition

```
private color: "green";
```

should be

```
private color:string = "green";
```

**alternative approach (preferred)**

A better way would be to use `@HostBinding()` instead

```
@Directive({
    selector: "[highlight]"
})
export class HighLightCmp implements OnInit{

    @HostBinding('style.background-color')
    private color: "green";
}
```

`@HostBinding()` can also be combined with `@Input()` to be able to pass the value from the outside like `[highlight]="red"`:

```
    @HostBinding('style.background-color')
    @Input()
    private color: "green";
```

The only **downside** of this approach is that the style properties (or attribute and class) names you want to bind to, need to be known at development time, while with your `Renderer` approach, they can be dynamic (for example passed in to an `@Input()`

Comment: Thank you @Gunter. I appreciate your help.